# how to merge only the diff in a PR to a different branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have a branch called `release/app1/sprint1` from which I created my local branch `feature/app1/sprint1/task1`, I was constantly merging and pulling the changes from `release/app1/sprint1` to my local branch along with my own commits. There is a different branch called `release/app2/sprint1`. Now my lead is saying whatever changes I added as part of `feature/app1/sprint1/task1` those should be merged with `release/app2/sprint1` and not `release/app1/sprint1`. Is to possible to merge only the diff of `feature/app1/sprint1/task1` and `release/app1/sprint1` to a newly created branch from `release/app2/sprint1` ?

One way I have in mind is to manually add all the changes by copy paste to a new branch created from `release/app2/sprint1` and raise a pull request.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a patch file from the `diff` and `apply` it to the new branch

```sh
git diff <branch1> <branch2> > diff.patch
git checkout <branch3>
git apply diff.patch
```

which obviously, `<branch1>`, `<branch2>` and `<branch3>` are your specific branch names.